# Caused by kotlin.TypeCastException null cannot be cast to non-null type com.drivequant.drivekit.tripanalysis.entity.PostGenericResponse

Tags: android, kotlin

I have used divequant-driverkit sdk in my app but app getting crash on TripAnalysedReceiver.onReceive

lib code of class **TripAnalysedReceiver**

```
@androidx.annotation.Keep public abstract class TripAnalysedReceiver public constructor() : android.content.BroadcastReceiver {
    public final fun onReceive(context: android.content.Context, intent: android.content.Intent): kotlin.Unit { /* compiled code */ }

    public abstract fun onTripCancelled(context: android.content.Context, status: com.drivequant.drivekit.tripanalysis.service.recorder.CancelTrip): kotlin.Unit

    public abstract fun onTripReceived(context: android.content.Context, post: com.drivequant.drivekit.tripanalysis.entity.PostGeneric, response: com.drivequant.drivekit.tripanalysis.entity.PostGenericResponse): kotlin.Unit
}
```

**My class for receiver is :**

```
public class DriveQuantTripAnalysedReceiver extends TripAnalysedReceiver {


    @Override
    public void onTripReceived(@NotNull Context context, @NotNull PostGeneric postGeneric, @NotNull PostGenericResponse postGenericResponse) {
        Log.e("TRIP ANALYSED", "New trip analysed");
       
    }

    @Override
    public void onTripCancelled(@NotNull Context context, @NotNull CancelTrip cancelTrip) {

    }
}
```

I don't know what's the exact issue, I just extended `TripAnalysedReceiver` on my class

**Error is :**

```
Caused by kotlin.TypeCastException
null cannot be cast to non-null type com.drivequant.drivekit.tripanalysis.entity.PostGenericResponse
com.drivequant.drivekit.tripanalysis.receiver.TripAnalysedReceiver.onReceive
android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:2953)
android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14 (ActivityThread.java)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1607)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:111)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:227)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6102)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:961)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:822)
```

Note : Lib projected implemented in kotlin and My project implemented in java

Comment: `response: PostGenericResponse` in the `onTripReceived()` is non-nullable field, are you passing null to it?

Comment: no I'm not passing any value on `onTripReceived()`

Comment: The library doesn't guarantee the values are going to be non-null but you annotated the implementation with `@NotNull`. It is possible that library returning `null` values whereas you expect them to be non-null

Comment: yes but lib not accepted null values `onTripReceived(context: android.content.Context, post: com.drivequant.drivekit.tripanalysis.entity.PostGeneric, response: com.drivequant.drivekit.tripanalysis.entity.PostGenericResponse)` then how it's possible?

Comment: In Kotlin `PostGenericResponse` is actually a non-nullable type, the `PostGenericResponse?` is a nullable type similar to java. Probably you could try to specify the library / method sending null value to get a better response.

Comment: yeah but it's should be fixed in library project